# How to suppress image not found error in console, nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, http-status-code-404

I wrote this component to show profile images or placeholder depending of its availability. It works but unfortunately the 404 not found error is still printed in the console, which shouldn't be the case. Any idea to suppress that?

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import {SyntheticEvent, useState} from 'react';

interface ProfileImageProps {
    customerNumber: string;
    alt: string;
    [key: string]: any;
}

const ProfileImage = ({ customerNumber, alt, ...otherProps }: ProfileImageProps) => {
    const [imageError, setImageError] = useState(false);
    const imageUrl = `https://externalapi/${customerNumber}.png`;
    const placeholderImageUrl = '/images/profile_placeholder.png';

    const imageLoader = ({ src, width }: { src: string; width: number }) => {
        if (imageError) {
            return `${placeholderImageUrl}?w=${width}&h=${width}`;
        }
        return `${src}?w=${width}&q=75`;
    };

    const handleImageError = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLImageElement, Event>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setImageError(true);
    };

    return (
        <Image
            src={imageUrl}
            alt={alt}
            onError={handleImageError}
            loader={imageLoader}
            width={100}
            height={100}
            {...otherProps}
        />
    );
};

export default ProfileImage;
```